# 'Memory leak' when calling openopt SNLE in a loop

Tags: python, memory-leaks, numpy, scipy

Whenever I run the solver 'interalg' (in the SNLE function call from OpenOpt) in a loop my memory usage accumulates until the code stops running.
It happen both in my Mac Os X 10.6.8 and in Slackware Linux.
I would really appreciate some advice, considering that I am not extremely literate in python.

Thank you!

Daniel

Comment: What do you mean by code stops running? you mean your process crashes? is there a 4gb dump when the crash occurs?

Answer (score 2):

Yes, there is clearly a memory leak here. I ran the nlsp demo, that uses SNLE with interalg, using valgrind and found that 295k has been leaked from running the solver once. This should be reported to them.

Answer (score 1):

This issue was due to memory leak in numpy.take(), and seems to be fixed in today's commit
http://forum.openopt.org/viewtopic.php?pid=1638#p1638